# Formatar data SQL dentro do Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Existe alguma formula em DAX que consiga alterar o formato de data importada pelo serviços do Power BI e manter o mesmo formato data, ou deixar em algum formato de  ordenação das datas?

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de uma função DAX para alterar o formato de data importada. Você pode ir diretamente para o editor de consultas e alterar os formatos dos campos conforme desejar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função DAX **Format** ou pode alterar o tipo de dados do campo no **Menu** Modelação > Tipo de Dados > Formato.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também alterar criando uma tabela virtual e alterando o formado como deseja:
medida = format([data],"MMM/YYY") ou format([data],"MMM") e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).